# Pass data from one thread to another (constantly)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have two constantly running threads:

1. The Producer - each iteration it generates values and puts them into an array of int. The array is passed to the Consumer thread. The Producer will not use the generated values again.
2. The Consumer - each iteration it creates a string from the received array and prints the outcome to the console.

There is an order of the generated array values. It should be the same in both threads.

---

```
public class Producer
{
    private int[] m_outputData;

    private Random m_numberGenerator = null;

    private Thread m_runner = null;

    private Consumer m_consumer = null;

    public Producer()
    {
        m_outputData = new int[10];

        m_numberGenerator = new Random();

        m_runner = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run));
        m_runner.IsBackground = true;

        m_consumer = new Consumer();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        m_consumer.Start();

        m_runner.Start();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < m_outputData.Length; i++)
            {
                m_outputData[i] = m_numberGenerator.Next(1, 100);
            }

            m_consumer.SetData(m_outputData);

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    private int[] m_inputData;

    private Thread m_runner = null;

    private readonly object m_dataLock = new object();

    public Consumer()
    {
        m_inputData = new int[10];

        m_runner = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run));
        m_runner.IsBackground = true;
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        m_runner.Start();
    }

    public void SetData(int[] arr)
    {
        lock (m_dataLock)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < m_inputData.Length; i++)
            {
                m_inputData[i] = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string data = "";

            lock (m_dataLock)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < m_inputData.Length; i++)
                {
                    data += m_inputData[i].ToString();
                    data += ",";
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(data);

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, I use a simple loop to copy the values one by one. This loop is protected by a lock. I have lokked into the Array.Copy method, however, it looks more expensive in use with a small arrays (function call).

What would be the most optimal way to pass the array (performance wise) between my threads?

Comment: ConcurrentQueue<T> would get rid of the lock.  You could use BlockingCollection<T> if you want the thread to block until data is received.  I wouldn't do this with large arrays though.  You'd also have to copy the array, not share a reference to it.

Comment: Why does the producer start the consumer? It is not a good practice for the producer to know its consumers. If they are threads of the same process, Program.cs should start both, they should synchronize using a wait handle etc.

Comment: As @Zer0 suggested, the communication should be indirect, using a ConcurrentQueue<EventData> kind of mechanism. If you want to continuosly write to the output, you try to [dequeue an item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1.trydequeue?view=netframework-4.8), and if it is not there, print "Not changed" or just the same array again

Comment: @OguzOzgul It has to be in the same process for `lock` to work.  Otherwise it would be a `Mutex`.  That said, I do agree.

Comment: @Zer0 yes I know. What I tried to say was (couldn't convey it, obviously), this is an in-proc producer/consumer scenario, but we should think more generally, where the producer and consumer are different processes, or even run on different servers. That's why I expect the Run() method to create both the producer and consumer and tie them up to each other by providing the indirect messaging tool, in terms of a queue, shared memory, etc.

Comment: @Zer0 Thank you for your fast reply. In my case the order of the values in the array has a meaning. I will update the question. sorry for that. I am looking at the BlockingCollection. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @OguzOzgul Thank you for your input. I have a manager thread that has several workers that produce the data.

Comment: A great solution is to use the [TPL DataFlow Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-a-producer-consumer-dataflow-pattern). This is one of the best ways to do producer/consumer in C#. It's thread-safe and offers a wide array of configuration options.

Comment: I've posted a simple implementation. It is not complete, because your posted code is, I think, not what you have for real. For your posted code however where there is one producer and one consumer which is notified when new data is available, it should work. (Not meant to be a solution, but to show another approach

Comment: I've changed the ref int[] approach to ConcurrentQueue. It supports multiple consumers now. The producer delays randomly between 100 and 200 milliseconds (deliberately) to simulate data production latency. Consumer prints out every 100 ms.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: Use of ConcurrentQueue to support multiple consumers

This is a very simple producer/consumer example using Task.Run() rather than threads.

A very important point here is that the implementations of the producer and consumer are de-coupled completely. and uses a `ConcurrentQueue` to share information between the producer and its consumers.

```
private static void Producer(ConcurrentQueue<int[]> eventQueue, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Random m_numberGenerator = new Random();

    while (true)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        int[] m_outputData = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < m_outputData.Length; i++)
        {
            m_outputData[i] = m_numberGenerator.Next(1, 100);
        }

        eventQueue.Enqueue(m_outputData);

        Thread.Sleep(m_numberGenerator.Next(100, 201));
    }
}

private static void Consumer(ConcurrentQueue<int[]> eventQueue, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (true)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        int[] m_inputData;
        if (eventQueue.TryDequeue(out m_inputData))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", m_inputData));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No new data is available.");
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConcurrentQueue<int[]> eventQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<int[]>();

    CancellationTokenSource consumerTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken consumerCancellationToken = consumerTokenSource.Token;

    Task.Run(() => Consumer(eventQueue, consumerCancellationToken), consumerCancellationToken);

    CancellationTokenSource producerTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken producerCancellationToken = consumerTokenSource.Token;

    Task.Run(() => Producer(eventQueue, producerCancellationToken), producerCancellationToken);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any ket to exit.");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
No new data is available.
8 57 70 28 78 58 40 79 39 87
61 5 12 75 21 56 77 15 96 29
No new data is available.
33 89 26 11 51 72 28 41 78 84
No new data is available.
92 74 80 54 78 24 78 68 46 16
64 78 84 88 40 60 46 1 41 81
19 25 80 2 68 7 68 51 98 9
No new data is available.
67 13 38 95 66 78 54 36 29 82
No new data is available.
53 25 48 26 63 32 68 94 78 43
89 56 55 73 76 55 71 1 95 18
20 12 71 51 45 93 68 46 5 52
No new data is available.
45 72 56 54 42 44 36 83 5 31
54 24 82 40 92 2 98 64 29 87
81 6 37 54 13 87 74 26 32 39
No new data is available.
68 11 83 18 22 14 28 64 13 14
18 58 48 69 5 2 67 48 40 24
No new data is available.
89 91 51 18 87 32 48 9 78 98
92 55 71 57 75 79 85 37 64 74
No new data is available.
40 87 79 7 43 82 73 59 84 98
35 21 92 67 5 27 96 16 4 35
55 65 93 97 48 26 87 62 4 59
No new data is available.
47 51 63 39 81 88 66 36 20 15
No new data is available.
55 21 50 65 9 75 59 41 48 71
98 33 14 14 46 35 47 72 22 95
No new data is available.
75 74 42 4 66 45 8 50 67 15
89 10 72 48 82 17 12 4 62 12
```